# python class id

Tags: python, class, tree

I search for a nice Implementation for a class with ids. My problem is, I don't know a good solution for pointing to other objects. My code will look like:

```
class node(object):
    counter = itertools.count().next
    def __init__(self)
        self.id = node.counter
        self.parent = ...
        self.children = ...
        self.neighbour = ...
```

I want to refer to other nodes like self.parent = node[id] - similar to a list

edit: So, cause there is much confusion, I want specify my question.
You can image node is a cube which has cubes in it, and is (maybe) inside a cube. So the subcubes are also cubes I want to refer in the class.
So my main idea was to organize it like a tree.

edit2: No, I'm not talking about a binary tree. At the end I would like to do things like:

```
node[4].children[0].children[2].neighbour[3].parent
```

Comment: That's completely doable, but not very sane.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information about the tree? Should it follow  a certain structure? Is it binary, or is the number of children not determined?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It is from a java perspective . I'd like to hear how python does this as well.

Comment: Java can't even *do* what you're asking, since you can't override indexing on a class.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm not the OP :p And of course Java can refer to other nodes within a node class. Are you perhaps interpreting his question too literally?

Comment: He has a class called "node", and he has a container called "node". What should I think?

Comment: My tree will be used to identify a AMR-structure. So every node has 8 children or None. 6 or lesser neighbours and one/no parent.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's still way too literal :p He wants to be able to refer to lists of other nodes within a node object (I think). And I think the `node[id]` part means that he wants to access this list of nodes within the object. OP, correct me if I'm wrong (and perhaps edit your question if I'm not).

Comment: Yeah that's what I want to do, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't understand your question, but the [`__*item__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) methods define the various indexing operations on both sequences and mappings in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a dynamic language, so attributes can be bound with any type.

```
class node( object ):
    def __init__( self, data, left, right ):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

[Here's](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/286239-binary-ordered-tree/) a nice example of an ordered tree using a node class, in python.

Comment: no, i'm not talking about a binary tree. At the end I would like to do things like: `node[4].children[0].children[2].neighbour[3].parent`

Comment: I know you're not. I'm saying you can use this information to create whatever structure you want. This will allow you to chain references the way you want to. But the bracket, [X], is still weird notation. Maybe store the nodes in lists within the node class instead.